# NgForm no muestra nada

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Tengo el siguiente problema no se si yo he importado mal ng Form pero al momento de implementarlo en el form todos los componentes desaparecen y se queda en blanco el navegador y ya no puedo retornar a componentes anteriores   del componente y a mi parecer he seguido los pasos que se indican en su web pero me sigue generando el error la importo de la siguiente manera

```html
 <form class="form-signin" #crearForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "iniciarSesion(crearForm)">
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuarioService } from '../../Services/usuario-login.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private servicioLogin: UsuarioService, private _router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  iniciarSesion(crearForm: NgForm): void {
    var nickname: string = crearForm.value.nickname;
    var password: string = crearForm.value.password;
    var rol: number = crearForm.value.rol;
    this.servicioLogin.getUsuario(nickname, password, rol).subscribe(
      res => {
        var respuesta: number = res["Cod_Usuario"];
        console.log("respuesta" + respuesta);

        if (respuesta == 1) {
          swal.fire(
            'Good job!',
            'You clicked the button!',
            'success'
          )
        }
      }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);

      },
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien más tiene este problema la solucion esta en importar forms y httpClientModule en app.module.ts al igual que los servicios que se hubieran programado